# Present perfect with past tense VS two present perfect

Tags: prepositions, past-tense, present-perfect

Which is the correct one?

"Ever since I met you, you have never asked me what I prefer"

Compare to

"Ever since I have met you, you have never asked me what I prefer"

Comment: Two people's first meeting is a one-off event, so you should say _Ever since I met you_. However, you could say _Ever since I have known you..._ since knowing (being acquainted with) them is an ongoing situation.

Comment: I think it's relatively unusual (stylistically clumsy) to include the word ***ever*** before ***since*** in an assertion featuring negation conveyed by ***never***. The more natural forms are ("positive") ***[Ever] since** then it **always** happens* and ("negative") ***Since** then it **never** happens*

Comment: Arguably the first part of the sentence is redundant. Another way to phrase it is "You have never asked me what I prefer in all the time I have known you."

Comment: 'Ever since I have met you…' simply will not work. Acceptable options include 'Since I met you…' and 'Since meeting you…' but 'I have met you…' works only in the sense of 'I have met you before…' which might be expressed as a question: 'I have met you, haven't I?' or an affirmation: 'Yes, I have met you…'